# Should I also send a cover letter along with my CV while applying to PhD programs in math

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, etiquette, email, application-cover-letter

I will apply to a PhD program in math at  French universities for session 2022.

I will write e-mails to  the professors I want to work with, asking if there are open PhD positions in their group. I plan to attach my CV (4 pages long)  along with the e-mail. Should I also attach a cover letter along with CV in e-mail? Why or Why not?

Comment: What would you put in the cover letter?

Comment: @Jeroen I am not sure, I applied to an institute which was asking for cover letter and CV separately and in that I wrote about why specifically  my branch of Math is interesting to me  and my interest in other branches in math and  my motivation to apply for phd and their institute

Comment: This answer gives you some more insights into the application process in France: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/171564/69838, especially this link in the answer: https://www.campusfrance.org/en/how-to-enrol-Doctorate-France. There you can find more about the requirements and procedures. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Jeroen Not really

Comment: In my experience, at least when contacting faculty individually, the cover letter is your statement of interest that you put in the body of your initial email. Of course, if the faculty's website has specific instructions for applicants, those whould be followed instead.